# How do I count whitespace lexemes (token)?

Tags: programming-languages, tokenize

I'm studying programming language with ocw(stanford).

x=0;\n\twhile (x < 10) { \n \tx++; \n }

I understood that consecutive space,\n,\t count as one whitespace token. But in the lecture, it says the number of tokens is 9 in the sentence above. I thought it was 7.

Can you tell me if the lecture is right or if I am right? If the lecture is right, how does it have 9 tokens?

[the way I count]

```
x=0;\n\twhile (x < 10) { \n \tx++; \n }
    1        2  3 4   5 6           7
```